# 18.04 server installer loop after setting IPv4 static config

Tags: system-installation

I'm testing 18.04 server in VirtalBox. In the machine config I have one eth interface and network set to internal network only.
During the 18.04 installation questions at the network configuration section I change the DHCP default option and Edit IPv4 and set static entries which are all accepted but when I hit 'Done' the installer loops back to the initial language selection page. All selection options are as previously selected except when I get back to the network configuration section and the interface is again set to DHCP.
Any help would be great as this is really bugging me.

Answer (score 2):

Don't provide a domain search list. The installer happily copes with data in the other fields and will set the fixed IP address as desired without looping back to language selection. Unfortunately, the console log flashes by too quickly when the installer loops back if you set a search list to be of use.

Comment: This is the right answer for my instance.  I was providing the search domain and on save it would send me back to language selection.  Although using an older image, this should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the new style Ubiquity NG installer doesn't like that network configuration.
I downloaded the alternate image that uses the previous installer and it worked fine.
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.2/release/?_ga=2.266705164.365025349.1554521143-1188865937.1520487584